# Can't iterate through a dataframe while comparing to dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have both a dictionary and a dataframe, and I'm attempting to iterate through each row of the dataframe, comparing a specific column of the df to the value of the corresponding dictionary key.  I am doing this through a for loop.  However I keep getting errors.

One type error I'm getting is: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.  I understand the genesis of this error, however when I try to change the keys of the dictionary to string types, they remain as object types.  If I try to change the entire dictionary to a string type, then when I run my for loop, I get a type error of string indices must be integers.

Thanks for any help, not sure what direction to go in here.

Here is the dictionary (otc_dict):

```
{'ALIVE MENS 50+': 0.25,
 'AM LACTATE 12% LOTION': 0.11089,
 'AMOX/CLAV 875MG TABS': 1.32,
  'APAP 325MG TABS (GH).': 0.03,
  'APAP 500MG (GH)': 0.05,
  'AQUAPHOR OINT': 0.11105999999999999,
  'AVEENO ULT-CALM SPF 15': 0.14125,
  'B-COMPLEX (GH)': 0.05,
  'BABY SHAMPOO': 0.01329,
  'BABY SHAMPOO J&J': 0.01995,
  'BACITRACIN FOIL PACK': 0.208,
  'BACLOFEN 10MG TABS': 0.185,
  'BATH CHAIR WITH BACK': 69.95,
  'BENZONATATE 100MG CAP': 0.49833,
  'BENZOYL PEROX 5% WASH 227*': 0.08789}
```

Here is the dataframe (aug_new):

```
      Rx Number Drug Name           Price Per
 0  0903-333 00 MELATONIN 5MG           0.083333
 1  0903-460 00 MULTIVI W/MINERALS (GH) 0.060000
 2  0903-632 00 RISPERIDONE 2MG TAB*    0.531667
 3  0903-633 00 CLONIDINE 0.1MG TAB*    0.165833
 4  0903-634 00 RISPERIDONE 3MG TAB*    0.598333
 5  0904-192 00 MULTIVITAMINS TABS (GH) 0.050000
 6  0895-624 06 VIT D3 2000IU TABS  0.100000
 7  0896-257 03 MULTIVI W/MINERALS (GH) 0.060000
```

Here is the for loop I'm attempting:

```
outliers = []
for row in aug_new.index:
    price = aug_new['Price Per']
    drug = aug_new['Drug Name']
    value = otc_dict[drug]
    rx = aug_new['Rx Number']
    if price != value:
        outliers.append(rx)
```

Basically I'm simply trying to make a list of Rx Numbers whose "Price Per" does not match the corresponding price from the drug name in the dictionary.

Comment: `aug_new['Price Per']` will return you the whole Series and you only want a single value so `aug_new.iloc[row]['Price Pre']` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `price = aug_new['Price Per']`, you are using the entire column (series) of 'Price per' instead of just the value in that row.

You can use:

```
outliers = []
for idx in aug_new.index:
    price = aug_new.loc[idx, 'Price Per']
    drug = aug_new.loc[idx, 'Drug Name']
    value = otc_dict[drug]
    rx = aug_new.loc[idx, 'Rx Number']
    if price != value:
        outliers.append(rx)
```

or use `df.iterrows()`:

```
outliers = []
for idx , row in aug_new.iterrows():
    price = row['Price Per']
    drug = row['Drug Name']
    value = otc_dict[drug]
    rx = row['Rx Number']
    if price != value:
        outliers.append(rx)
```

If computation time is an issue, the `.loc[]` method is faster. 
(Example from another dataset):

```
%timeit for idx, row in df.iterrows(): print(row['DateTime'])
1.3 ms ± 25.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit for idx in df.index: print(df.loc[idx, 'DateTime'])
619 µs ± 23.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you @Niels Henkens

Comment: An upvote and/or acceptance of an answer is always appreciated if the answer is helpful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
price = aug_new['Price Per']
```

Try:

```
price = aug_new.iloc[row]['Price Per']
```

The 1st returns you an entire series, defeating the purpose of iterating over the rows. Whereas the second returns you the specific value stored at the index row and the column 'Price Per'.

The same applies to the rest of the assignments.
Note that specifically, the error is due to

```
drug = aug_new['Drug Name']
value = otc_dict[drug]
```

This returns you the series of 'drugs', rather than a single string value, and is an invalid key for the dictionary 'otc_dict'.